# AVR Assembly Language Code

Tags: assembly, avr

I am stuck on the following code and don't have a basic understand of how it works?

Determine the decimal value of `r22` after the following line of code is executed:

```
clr r22  

dec r22

push r22

dec r22

pop r5
```

**value of r22 = ?**

Comment: Why not run it to find out?

Comment: The [AVR Instruction Set](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0856.pdf) starting page 11 should give a listing of exactly what the instructions do.

Answer (score 2):

Well, just work through each instruction one at a time and figure out what each one does.

1. **clr r22**: This sets the register to 0.
2. **dec r22**: This decrements it, so it underflows from 0 to 255.
3. **push r22**: This pushes 255 (r22) onto the stack.
4. **dec r22**: This decrements r22, so r22 is now 254.
5. **pop r5**: This pops a value (255) off the stack and stores it in r5, not affecting r22.

So, unless I got something wrong, the answer is r22 = 254.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realise that dec r22 would go from 0 to 255.

Comment: Ok, but if we interpret the decimal value as signed then it is -2.

Answer (score 0):

The register(in 8bit) goes from 0 to FF(dec r22) to FE(dec r22)

If r22 is 4 bit then E = 14

If r22 is 8 bit then FE = 254

if r22 is 16 bit then FFFE = 65534

and so on

A processor register is like a car mileometer
When it reaches 99,999 miles it goes forwards to 00000

A register reaches F-F-F-F, 15-15-15-15 (not 9-9-9-9 because it's hex not decimal) and when we +1 it returns to 0-0-0-0

Comment: _"If r22 is 8 bit then E = 14"_  No, `r22` would be `0xFE` in that case. `0xE` is only 4 bits.

Comment: I think it was an 8 bit register they were asking for but I think I now understand it. Thank you for your help.